# composite-video-to-usb adaptor

Tags: drivers, video, usb

I bought a composite-video-to-usb adaptor. I want to stream video game in ubuntu. How can I do that?

My environment:

- Monoprice USB Video and Audio Grabber
- Ubuntu 11.04

The relevant output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 0572:262a Conexant Systems (Rockwell), Inc.
```

The relevant output of `sudo lshw`:

```
    *-usb:0
         description: USB Controller
         product: 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1a
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.0
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: uhci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
         resources: irq:16 ioport:f0e0(size=32)
    *-usb:1
         description: USB Controller
         product: 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1a.1
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.1
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: uhci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
         resources: irq:21 ioport:f0c0(size=32)
    *-usb:2
         description: USB Controller
         product: 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1a.2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.2
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: uhci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
         resources: irq:18 ioport:f0a0(size=32)
    *-usb:3
         description: USB Controller
         product: 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1a.7
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.7
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=ehci_hcd latency=0
         resources: irq:18 memory:e0525c00-e0525fff
    *-multimedia
         description: Audio device
         product: 82801JI (ICH10 Family) HD Audio Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1b
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
         version: 00
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=HDA Intel latency=0
         resources: irq:43 memory:e0520000-e0523fff
    *-usb:4
         description: USB Controller
         product: 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1d
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: uhci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
         resources: irq:23 ioport:f080(size=32)
    *-usb:5
         description: USB Controller
         product: 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1d.1
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.1
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: uhci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
         resources: irq:19 ioport:f060(size=32)
    *-usb:6
         description: USB Controller
         product: 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1d.2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.2
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: uhci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
         resources: irq:18 ioport:f040(size=32)
    *-usb:7
         description: USB Controller
         product: 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1d.7
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.7
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=ehci_hcd latency=0
         resources: irq:23 memory:e0525800-e0525bff
```

The relevant output of `dmesg`:

```
[18953.220035] usb 1-1: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 6
[19964.761076] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[19964.767112] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[19964.767115] USB Video Class driver (v1.0.0)
```

Comment: please add to your question the output of lsusb - need to identify how ubuntu sees your USB device.  Also it would be useful to see the output of sudo lshw

Comment: @fossfreedom I added the information that you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

If you are lucky, your capture device will be recognized as soon as you plug it in and be ready to use.  If you do `ls /dev/video*` you should see the device.  Assuming it is the only one plugged in, it will either be /dev/video or /dev/video0.

If you don't see the device, you may have to look for the appropriate driver. [This post](http://www.salixos.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=3271) suggest that it is really a Geniaech EZ Grabber that has been rebranded, and it uses the uvcvideo driver.

To test the device, you can use mplayer: `mplayer /dev/video` should do it.

I like [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/) for most things, and it can do video streaming from a capture device.  You can install VLC from Synaptic.  VLC is pretty pretty straight forward to use, but [this entry from the VLC Documentation Wiki](http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation%3aStreaming_HowTo/Easy_Streaming_Newer_Versions) should get you started.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. `/dev/video` or `/dev/video1` do not seem to exist. I am trying to make the `uvcvideo` driver work. Search on the website suggest that ubuntu 11.04, which I am using, should have it already, but I cannot make it work. I am not sure if it helps, but I added information from dmesg to my question.

Comment: @sawa I'm not sure what else to suggest.  You might try doing an `ls -lt /dev | head` and see what the latest devices added were and see if they might be the correct one.  Other then that, I would search the device ID (0572:262a) and see what it says.